# AWS Cloudformation Template help for IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am new to creating templates in Cloudformattion.
I have a requirement where i Need to create a IAM user with  password and access keys , password should be changed upon first time login , a I AM group should be create where in the group a set of manageg policy and custom policy should be added .

How do I go with this , please help

Thanks
satish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'IAM user'
Parameters:
  UserName:
    Type: String
  Password:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
Resources:
  Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
    Properties: 
      LoginProfile:
        Password: !Ref Password
        PasswordResetRequired: true
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'
      UserName: !Ref UserName
```

next time: why not just use google?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html and the password is set in the LoginProfile http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user-loginprofile.html

Comment: great , this comes close to what I needed, it would be of help if you can suggest me how to add this user  to a group , where the group will have all the managed policies and custom policy instead of adding directly to the user .